# how to convert from a list of generics to list of objects in java 8?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have this List of generics `List<? super Domain>`,containing to implementation of Domain: Material and BoM,now I want to get each entity separately.

```
domainList.stream().filter(a -> a.getClass().equals(BoM.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with this line i have `List<? super Domain>` that only contains BoM object.my problem is how to convert this list to `List<BoM>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'd do it like this:

```
List<BoM> boms = domainList.stream()
            .filter(BoM.class::isInstance)
            .map(BoM.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```